# Implementing Class Level inheritance with t4scafolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, inheritance

I am testing a project having multiple projects as follows:
1. Project.Mvc
2. Project.DomainClasses
3. Project.DataLayer

In Project.DomainClasses, I have implemented Class Level inheritance as follows

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee:Person
{
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I installed t4scaffolding through package manager console. After that I created another project for DataLayer called Project.DataLayer, installed entity framework and referenced Project.DomainClasses. Now, when I tried to use the t4scafold creating the context with the following command in the package manager console:

```
Scaffold Repository Project.DomainClasses.Employee -DbContextType:EmployeeContext
```

I am getting the following error:

---

Get-PrimaryKey : Cannot find primary key property for type Project.DomainClasses.Employee'. Multiple properties appear to be primary keys: PersonId, EmployeeId
At C:\Project\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.8\tools\EFRepository\T4Scaffolding.EFRepository.ps1:19 char:29
+ $primaryKey = Get-PrimaryKey <<<<  $foundModelType.FullName -Project $Project -ErrorIfNotFound
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-PrimaryKey], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.GetPrimaryKeyCmdlet

---

This is my first-time trying to implement inheritance in database level. Before implementing this I went through different articles in msdn and stackoverflow. But, I am stuck now.
Thanks in advance for helping me and your time.

Comment: I tried the same for the models not using the inheritance and that work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple. I was confused in the primary key of the derived class. As the database should have derived class with primary key which also act as foreign key to the base class, I was trying to add the EmployeeId and declare it as foreign key which was causing the problem. So, the solution is:

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee:Person
{
// Remove EmployeeID property
//Add other properties if exists else leave it as empty class
}
```